# Docker: can a cmdline argument be appended to a shell built-in command args?

Tags: docker, exit-code, docker-entrypoint, docker-command

I want to create a docker image with a cmdline-specifiable exit code.
From this question, I learned that I must use `exit` as an argument to `sh` because it is a shell built-in command, not an executable: [How to make a docker container exit with a specific error-code with docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71302454/how-to-make-a-docker-container-exit-with-a-specific-error-code-with-docker-compo)

I.e. I can create a docker container that exits with error-code 42 as follows:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.15 as base
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "exit 42"]
```

```
$ docker build -t tmp:tmp . && docker run tmp:tmp
[+] Building 0.4s (5/5) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 181B                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.15                                0.0s
 => CACHED [1/1] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:3.15                                           0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                        0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                       0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:3034115e85f4ac9322c3e3e5d69f4445e30cc652f3b836d0145545305fda6ad1  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/tmp:tmp                                                    0.0s
$ echo $?
42
$
```

**Question:**
**Can the docker container be made to return an exit-code specified as a cmdline argument?**
E.g. is this possible:

```
$ docker build -t tmp:tmp . && docker run tmp:tmp 64
...
$ echo $?
64
$
```

?

**What I've tried:**
This article -- https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/ -- led me to try this combination of `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.15 as base
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "exit"]
CMD ["0"]
```

```
$ docker build -t tmp:tmp . && docker run tmp:tmp 64
...
$ echo $?
0
```

Interestingly, this same "pattern" of Dockerfile worked for `echo`:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.15 as base
ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "hello"]
CMD ["world"]
```

```
$ docker build -t tmp:tmp . && docker run tmp:tmp
...
hello world
$
$ docker build -t tmp:tmp . && docker run tmp:tmp foo
...
hello foo
$
```

I think my failed experiment with `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` is explained by this experiment:

```
$ sh -c "exit 42"
$ echo $?
42
$ sh -c "exit" 42
$ echo $?
0
```

...I hoped that my Dockerfile with `ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "exit"]` and `CMD ["0"]` would result in the former, but I think it results in the latter -- true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your docker run arguments are being passed to your `entrypoint.sh` if you have one defined.

For example in my Dockerfile I have:

```
# prepare container
COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And in my entrypoint.sh

```
printf "Custom exit code '$*'\n"
exit "$@"
```

And then just run with args:

```
$ docker run verify 129
Custom exit code '129'
$ echo $?
129
$ _
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, `CMD` always passes its contents as new arguments to the entrypoint. You cannot insert it as part of an argument from `ENTRYPOINT`.

I'd also recommend Florin's solution, that is, having a custom entrypoint. However, if you really need to, you can still do it with shell only:

```
from alpine

entrypoint ["/bin/sh", "-c", "exit \"$@\"", "sh"]

cmd ["42"]
```

This will run `sh` with 4 arguments, being `-c`, `exit "$@"`, `sh` and `42` (or your command). The last two arguments are what will be passed to the script as `argv[0]` (which is the name of the shell itself) and `argv[1]`, the first argument, which will be substituted into `$@`.